# The description for Event ID 1234 from source Application cannot be found

Tags: event-handling, eventlog-source

In the eventviewer I see the following error:

The description for Event ID 1234 from source Application cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

However when I try to add the source with the following command I get an error "Source Application already exists on the local computer."
[System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource("Application", "Application")

Exception calling "CreateEventSource" with "2" argument(s): "Source Application already exists on the local computer."
At line:1 char:1

- [System.Diagnostics.EventLog]::CreateEventSource("Application", "Appl ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
  ```

When I check the registry, the source seems to be existing as well.

So how can I add the source Application to get a wellformed error in my eventlog?